# Firebase authentication, IOS results in PlatformException

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Trying to use firebase authentication. Works perfectly for Android, but for IOS I am getting PlatformException(ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information., null). Biggest issue is the error has no details.

Flutter Doctor reports no issues.

```
   globals.user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: pw,
        ))
            .user;
```

```
Restarted application in 1,443ms.
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information., null)
[38;5;244m#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope[39;49m
[38;5;244m#1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod[39;49m
<asynchronous suspension>
[38;5;244m#2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod[39;49m
<asynchronous suspension>
[38;5;248m#3      FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword[39;49m
<asynchronous suspension>
[38;5;248m#4      _HomePageState._retrieveAccountInfo[39;49m
<asynchronous suspension>
[38;5;248m#5      _HomePageState.initState[39;49m
[38;5;244m#6      StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#7      ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#8      Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#9      Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#10     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#11     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#12     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#13     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#14     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#15     ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#16     ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#17     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#18     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#19     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#20     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#21     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#22     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#23     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#24     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#25     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#26     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#27     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#28     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#29     ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#30     StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#31     ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#32     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#33     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#34     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#35     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#36     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#37     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#38     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#39     ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#40     StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#41     ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#42     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#43     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#44     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#45     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#46     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#47     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#48     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#49     ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#50     StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#51     ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#52     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#53     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#54     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#55     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#56     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#57     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#58     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#59     ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#60     StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#61     ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#62     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#63     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#64     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#65     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#66     ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#67     ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#68     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#69     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#70     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#71     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#72     ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#73     StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#74     ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#75     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#76     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#77     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#78     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#79     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#80     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#81     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#82     ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#83     ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#84     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#85     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#86     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#87     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#88     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#89     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#90     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#91     ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#92     StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#93     ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#94     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#95     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#96     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#97     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#98     ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#99     ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#100    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#101    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#102    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#103    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#104    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#105    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#106    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#107    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#108    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#109    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#110    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#111    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#112    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#113    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#114    StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#115    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#116    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#117    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#118    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#119    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#120    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#121    StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#122    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#123    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#124    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#125    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#126    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#127    _TheatreElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#128    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#129    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#130    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#131    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#132    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#133    StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#134    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#135    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#136    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#137    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#138    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#139    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#140    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#141    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#142    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#143    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#144    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#145    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#146    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#147    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#148    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#149    StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#150    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#151    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#152    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#153    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#154    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#155    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#156    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#157    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#158    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#159    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#160    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#161    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#162    StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#163    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#164    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#165    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#166    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#167    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#168    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#169    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#170    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#171    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#172    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#173    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#174    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#175    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#176    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#177    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#178    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#179    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#180    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#181    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#182    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#183    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#184    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#185    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#186    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#187    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#188    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#189    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#190    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#191    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#192    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#193    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#194    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#195    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#196    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#197    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#198    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#199    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#200    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#201    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#202    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#203    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#204    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#205    StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#206    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#207    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#208    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#209    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#210    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#211    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#212    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#213    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#214    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#215    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#216    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#217    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#218    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#219    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#220    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#221    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#222    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#223    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#224    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#225    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#226    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#227    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#228    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#229    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#230    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#231    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#232    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#233    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#234    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#235    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#236    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#237    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#238    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#239    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#240    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#241    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#242    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#243    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#244    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#245    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#246    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#247    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#248    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#249    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#250    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#251    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#252    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#253    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#254    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#255    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#256    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#257    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#258    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#259    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#260    StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#261    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#262    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#263    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#264    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#265    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#266    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#267    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#268    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#269    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#270    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#271    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#272    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#273    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#274    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#275    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#276    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#277    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#278    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#279    StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#280    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#281    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#282    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#283    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#284    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#285    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#286    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#287    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#288    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#289    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#290    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#291    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#292    StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#293    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#294    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#295    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#296    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#297    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#298    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#299    StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#300    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#301    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#302    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#303    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244m#304    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244m#305    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure>[39;49m
[38;5;244m#306    BuildOwner.buildScope[39;49m
[38;5;244m#307    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree[39;49m
[38;5;244m#308    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244m#309    runApp[39;49m
[38;5;248m#310    main.<anonymous closure>[39;49m
[38;5;244m#311    _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#312    _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#313    _FutureListener.handleValue  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#314    Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#315    Future._propagateToListeners  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#316    Future._complete  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#317    _SyncCompleter.complete  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#318    _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete  (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:28:18)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#319    _completeOnAsyncReturn  (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:294:13)[39;49m
#320    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations (package:flutter/src/services/system_chrome.dart)
[38;5;244m#321    _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:77:64)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#322    _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#323    _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#324    _FutureListener.handleValue  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#325    Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#326    Future._propagateToListeners  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#327    Future._complete  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#328    _SyncCompleter.complete  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#329    _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete  (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:28:18)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#330    _completeOnAsyncReturn  (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:294:13)[39;49m
#331    OptionalMethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart)
[38;5;244m#332    _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:77:64)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#333    _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#334    _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#335    _FutureListener.handleValue  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#336    Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#337    Future._propagateToListeners  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#338    Future._complete  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#339    _SyncCompleter.complete  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#340    _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete  (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:28:18)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#341    _completeOnAsyncReturn  (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:294:13)[39;49m
#342    MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart)
[38;5;244m#343    _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:77:64)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#344    _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#345    _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#346    _FutureListener.handleValue  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#347    Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#348    Future._propagateToListeners  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#349    Future._completeWithValue  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:483:5)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#350    Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:513:7)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#351    _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#352    _CustomZone.run  (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#353    _CustomZone.runGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#354    _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#355    _microtaskLoop  (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#356    _startMicrotaskLoop  (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)[39;49m
```

Update: Tried using the swift version of firebase auth and got the exact same results. error code 17999 which Indicates an internal error occurred.